# How to get a URL of configurable product in product feed manager

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, google-product-feeds

I am new to Magento and cannot seem to get simple thing right.

We use "Data Feed Manager" to automatically create product feeds. We only include configurable products, thus each URL have to be of a configurable product.

As said, we only filter the configurable products, but the `{url}` variables always end up in 404.

If there is any information that should have been provided, just ask.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated in this case.

**UPDATE**

The `url` variable is generated as following:

```
$url = $product->getProductUrl(). '.html' ;
```

However, `getProductUrl()` returns domain name + url key of its parent product.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try adding .html to the end of the {urlkey}.

so if {url} = 'example'  try example.html

If you can post a more specific example of the values you are using perhaps someone can help.

---

OK i assume you are using this extension: https://www.wyomind.com/data-feed-manager-magento.html

If you look at the definition for `{url}` you will see - 'Retrieves the product's canonical absolute url.'. Because this is canonical - all associated products will point back to the main URL for the product page (no matter what the difference in attributes for the simple products).

Instead of using `{url}` try the `{uri}` instead - which promises: "Retrieves the product *canonical relative* url." with the `{host}` key as follows:

`{host}/{uri}.html`

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help. I have updated the question with slightly more information. Hopefully that will help.